# Find smallest value in column for each block using awk

Tags: bash, awk

I would like to find the smallest value of column $3, for each block which has a "header line" in the format of '@ value1 value2'. The file looks like this

```
@ 62.65 -50.35
0 1.50 1.676
1.67 1.50 1.677
1.67 2.25 1.423
2.90 2.25 2.902
2.90 4.95 2.903
3.04 4.95 3.049
@ 63.61 -50.45
0 1.50 1.654
3.42 1.50 1.875
3.43 2.19 3.430
5.31 2.19 1.032
5.32 6.23 5.320
5.43 6.23 5.434
```

After this, I want to print the header as well as the whole line with the smallest $3.

So, my output file should look like

```
@ 62.65 -50.35
1.67 2.25 1.423
@ 63.61 -50.45
5.31 2.19 1.032
```

This is what I tried so far:

```
awk '{if (!/^@/) {if ($3 < min) {$3=min;} print $1, $2, $3, min; min = $3;} else if (/^@/) min = 10; print $1 $2 $3;}' input.txt > output.txt
```

I have troubles to separate the blocks and to "reset" min (I tried to set the 'start' value high - i.e. 10).

I am new in programming and mainly used awk so far - if you could help me out, that would be really great! Thanks so much! Cheers, Isi

Comment: What is your expected output, can you edit the question and provide it.

Comment: Also, please add your attempt so far. It's okay if it doesn't work,

Comment: Welcome to SO. What did you try already? Do not hesitate to visit the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help).

Answer (score 3):

Using awk:

```
awk '/^@/{if(h){print h RS m}min=""; h=$0; next}min=="" || $3 < min{min=$3; m=$0}END{print h RS m}' infile
```

Using `array`

```
awk '/^@/{h=$0;min="";next}min==""||$3<min{min=$3;l[h]=$0}END{for(i in l)print i RS l[i]}' infile
```

Better Readable:

```
awk '/^@/{
          if(h){
               print h RS m
          }
          min=""; h=$0; next
         }
     min=="" || $3 < min{
          min=$3; 
          m=$0
     }
     END{
          print h RS m
     }
    ' infile
```

Using `array`

```
awk '/^@/{
          h=$0;min="";
          next
     }
     min==""||$3<min{
          min=$3;
          l[h]=$0
     }
     END{
          for(i in l)
               print i RS l[i]
     }
     ' infile
```

Test Results:

```
$ cat infile
@ 62.65 -50.35
0 1.50 1.676
1.67 1.50 1.677
1.67 2.25 1.423
2.90 2.25 2.902
2.90 4.95 2.903
3.04 4.95 3.049
@ 63.61 -50.45
0 1.50 1.654
3.42 1.50 1.875
3.43 2.19 3.430
5.31 2.19 1.032
5.32 6.23 5.320
5.43 6.23 5.434
```

Output-1 ( Recommended )

```
$ awk '/^@/{if(h){print h RS m}min=""; h=$0; next}min=="" || $3 < min{min=$3; m=$0}END{print h RS m}' infile
@ 62.65 -50.35
1.67 2.25 1.423
@ 63.61 -50.45
5.31 2.19 1.032
```

Output-2

```
$ awk '/^@/{h=$0;min="";next}min==""||$3<min{min=$3;l[h]=$0}END{for(i in l)print i RS l[i]}' infile
@ 62.65 -50.35
1.67 2.25 1.423
@ 63.61 -50.45
5.31 2.19 1.032
```

Comment: Same remark as about the other answer: using $0 as key of an associative array is debatable: what if there are several identical lines?

Comment: @RenaudPacalet: I agree with you, but at current context, I got one more solution, 1st one which will not override, previous one, since OP shown little data, and didn't mention whether there were any duplicates which need to be taken care, so I assumed, there could be unique lines which starts with `@`

Answer (score 1):

Awk can do this quite easily, as per the following script:

```
awk '
    $1=="@"    { first=1; key=$0; next }
    first==1   { lowest=$3; line[key]=$0; first=0; next }
               { if ($3 < lowest) { lowest=$3; line[key]=$0 } }
    END        { for (key in line) { printf "%s\n%s\n", key, line[key] } }
' <<EOF
@ 62.65 -50.35
0 1.50 1.676
1.67 1.50 1.677
1.67 2.25 1.423
2.90 2.25 2.902
2.90 4.95 2.903
3.04 4.95 3.049
@ 63.61 -50.45
0 1.50 1.654
3.42 1.50 1.875
3.43 2.19 3.430
5.31 2.19 1.032
5.32 6.23 5.320
5.43 6.23 5.434
EOF
```

As requested, the output is:

```
@ 62.65 -50.35
1.67 2.25 1.423
@ 63.61 -50.45
5.31 2.19 1.032
```

Breaking out the code for clarification:

```
$1=="@" {                # For all header lines:
    first=1              #    Flag that you're starting a new block.
    key=$0               #    Save the key.
    next                 #    Go back for next line.
}
first==1 {               # For first line in each block:
    lowest=$3            #    It must be lowest.
    line[key]=$0         #    Store line.
    first=0              #    Now processing subsequent lines in block.
    next                 # Go back for next line.
}
{                        # For non-first-lines-in-block:
    if ($3 < lowest) {   #    Only if this one is lower.
        lowest=$3        #    Store value and line.
        line[key]=$0
    }
}
END {                    # At end, simply output associative array.
    for (key in line) {
        printf "%s\n%s\n", key, line[key]
    }
}
```

---

Keep in mind this assumes the header lines are unique. If there can be duplicates and you want to treat them distinctly, you can create the key from a combination of `NR` and `$0`.

Comment: Oh wow, great! Thank you so much! That is a really big help. :)

Comment: Using `$0` as key of an associative array is debatable: what if there are several identical lines?

Comment: @RenaudPacalet: then you can just use `NR` in conjunction with `$0`, that will uniquely identify each block even if the lines can be duplicated. I'll add that as an option.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a totally different awk approach.

```
awk 'BEGIN {RS="@"} {s=$3 OFS $4 OFS $5; n=$5; for (i=5;i<=NF;i+=3) {if ($i<n) {s=$(i-2) OFS $(i-1) OFS $i; n=$5} }} n { print "@ " $1 OFS $2 ORS s }' infile
```

Or broken out for easier commenting:

```
BEGIN {
  RS="@"                          # "@" as our record separator
}

{
  s=$3 OFS $4 OFS $5              # store the first line...
  n=$5
  for (i=5;i<=NF;i+=3) {          # for each 3rd field on a line,
    if ($i<n) {                   # test its value and
      s=$(i-2) OFS $(i-1) OFS $i  # store a new value if the
      n=$5                        # condition matches
    }
  }
}

n {
  print "@ " $1 OFS $2 ORS s      # print records once we have them.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The following is yet another solution using awk command.

```
awk '
/^@/{if(b)print a;print $0;next}
!b||$3<b{b=$3;a=$0}
END{print a}
' infile

/^@/{if(b)print a;print $0;next}
```

for the line which start with @

if b is defined print a (on the first line a and b are not defined)

print the line and go to next line

```
!b||$3<b{b=$3;a=$0}
```

for each line whithout the line starting by @

if b is not defined or if $3 is lesser than b, keep $3 in b and keep the line in a

```
END{print a}
```

at the end, we must print the line stored in a

Comment: How does this work? Some explanation would be great.